# RubyMine doesn't recognize user created environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, ruby

**TLDR:** Basically RubyMine does not recognize any user created environment variable when launched from a desktop entry, but when launched from console (using `$ mine`) it can recognize all the environment variables. What could be wrong?

---

I am using Google Cloud Vision API and I've already set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to my service account private key file path.

When I launch `RubyMine` from a desktop entry and run the code below.

```
require 'google/cloud/vision'

image_annotator = Google::Cloud::Vision::ImageAnnotator.new
response = image_annotator.text_detection(
    image: "path_to_image_file",
    max_results: 1
)
```

It throws a `Runtime Error`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7: from /home/burak/RubymineProjects/covid19/main.rb:17:in `<main>'
        6: from /home/burak/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/google-cloud-vision-0.38.0/lib/google/cloud/vision.rb:169:in `new'
        5: from /home/burak/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/google-cloud-vision-0.38.0/lib/google/cloud/vision/v1.rb:166:in `new'
        4: from /home/burak/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/google-cloud-vision-0.38.0/lib/google/cloud/vision/v1.rb:166:in `new'
        3: from /home/burak/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/google-cloud-vision-0.38.0/lib/google/cloud/vision/v1/image_annotator_client.rb:122:in `initialize'
        2: from /home/burak/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/googleauth-0.12.0/lib/googleauth/credentials.rb:329:in `default'
        1: from /home/burak/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/googleauth-0.12.0/lib/googleauth/credentials.rb:361:in `from_application_default'
    /home/burak/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/googleauth-0.12.0/lib/googleauth/application_default.rb:76:in `get_application_default': Could not load the default credentials. Browse to (RuntimeError)
    https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
    for more information
```

But when I run the code from within `IRB` or when I launch `RubyMine` from console and run the same code, it runs successfully.

Comment: Set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` where? How?

Comment: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path_to_file` in `.bashrc`

Comment: Try putting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path_to_file` without the export in `~/.pam_environment` instead. The GUI doesn't read your .bashrc.

Comment: I've created the file and then put the expression but I still get the same Runtime Error.

Comment: You need to log out and login again for the GUI to see any changes there. Or just restart the system.

Comment: Oh now it works, thank you. Before it was not doing this, I guess I broke something.

Comment: As to where to set environment variables, yes. Thank you. :)